# Method of moments estimate of Pareto Distribution

Tags: self-study, estimators, cumulative-distribution-function, pareto-distribution, method-of-moments

> The Pareto distribution has the following $cumulative \  distribution \  function$ :
> $$F(x;\alpha ,\Theta ) = \left\{\begin{matrix}
> 1 - (\frac{\alpha}{x})^{\theta}\ \ if \  \alpha \leq x\ & \\ 0 \ \ \ \ \ \ \   \ otherwise
>  & 
> \end{matrix}\right.$$

> where $ 0< \alpha<\infty$ and $ 1< \theta<\infty$ are the parameters. Using moments method, find the estimates of $\alpha$ and $\theta$ based on a sample of size $5$ for value $3,5,2,7 \ and \ 8. $

To solve this question I began by determining the expectation using the CDF.

I found that you can compute the expectation directly from CDF when integrating as follows [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10159/find-expected-value-using-cdf)

$$E(X) = \int \left( 1 - F_X(x) \right) \,\mathrm{d}x$$

$$ = \int_\alpha^\infty \left( (\frac{\alpha}{x})^{\theta} \right) \,\mathrm{d}x$$

$$ = \frac{\alpha}{\theta -1} $$

$$ = \overline{X} = 5$$

How do I proceed from here?

Comment: Please add the `self-study` tag and read its wiki.

Answer (score 1):

The formula you use for the expectation holds for any non-negative valued random variable. However, if $X$ has the Pareto distribution in your post, then it is $X-\alpha$ and not $X$ that is non-negative.

The general formula changes as $$E(X-\alpha)I_{X\ge\alpha}=\int_{\alpha}^\infty (1-F(x))\,dx$$

Therefore, in this problem,

$$E(X)=E(XI_{X\ge \alpha})=\alpha+\int_{\alpha}^\infty (1-F(x))\,dx=\frac{\theta\alpha}{\theta-1} \qquad\left[\because\, \theta>1 \right]$$

Suppose $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ are i.i.d with the given cdf $F$.

The first moment equation is $$\frac1n\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i=\frac{\theta\alpha}{\theta-1} \tag{1}$$

You need another equation to solve for the two unknown parameters. This is provided by the second moment $E(X^2)$, but the second moment is finite provided $\theta>2$. As you do not have this assumption, one option is to find $E\left(\frac1{X}\right)$ using the pdf of $X$:

$$E\left(\frac1{X}\right)=\int_{\alpha}^\infty \frac1x\cdot\frac{\theta \alpha^\theta}{x^{\theta+1}}\,dx=\frac{\theta}{(\theta+1)\alpha}\qquad\left[\because\, \theta+1>0 \right]$$

The corresponding moment equation is

$$\frac1n\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac1{X_i}=\frac{\theta}{(\theta+1)\alpha} \tag{2}$$

Now you can eliminate $\alpha$ using $(1)$ and $(2)$ and solve for the method of moment estimator $\hat\theta$ of $\theta$. The corresponding estimator of $\alpha$ can then be obtained in terms of $\hat\theta$ from $(1)$. It is easy to verify that both estimators are consistent. If it was given that $\theta>2$, then a similar approach would have worked using the second moment.

Note that this is just one possible solution (see [How to use method of moment to find Pareto distribution estimator?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/305952/119261)). In Johnson-Kotz-Balakrishnan's *Continuous Univariate Distributions* (Volume 1, 2nd ed.), they discuss a solution due to [Quandt (1966)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02613419) where consistent method of moment estimators are obtained using the first moment and expectation of the first order statistic $X_{(1)}$, under the only assumption $\theta>1$.